# show values of mutiple properties in tool tip wpf XamDataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xamdatagrid

I have `xamdatgrid` which I add columns dynamically. I am adding a `ToolTip` to the column using following code.

```
Binding toolTipBinding = new Binding();
toolTipBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("DataItem.Property1");

Setter toolTipSetter = new Setter();
toolTipSetter.Property = ToolTipProperty;
toolTipSetter.Value = toolTipBinding;
cellValuePresenterStyle.Setters.Add(toolTipSetter);
```

Using this I was able to display the value of `Property1` as the `ToolTip`. I have another `Property` in the class (`property2`). I want to display the values of both `Properties` in the `ToolTip`. How can I achieve that

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why are you not doing it in XAML code. But if you do want to achieve this in using code behind. Then do following steps

1. Use MultiBinding class to do a binding of tooltip.
2. create two bindings for two properties (Property1 & Property2) and add them in multibinding you created in step 1 using Add method.
3. create a converter (**IMultiValueConverter**) to write a logic to concatinate property1 & property2.
4. Assign the binding in the setter value as you have already done.

> ```
> Binding b1=new Binding();
> ```
>
> `b1.Path = new PropertyPath("DataItem.Property1");`
>
> `Binding b2=new Binding();`
>
> `b2.Path = new PropertyPath("DataItem.Property2");`
>
> `var toolTipBinding = new MultiBinding();`
>
> `toolTipBinding.Bindings.Add(b1);`
> `toolTipBinding.Bindings.Add(b2);`
>
> `toolTipBinding.Converter = new ///your converter`